# guess game - index error - python

Tags: python, массивы, list

```
import random

def print3x3(lists):
  for i, item in enumerate(lists, 1):
    print(item, end=' ')
    if i % 3 == 0:
      print()

listx = list()
list0 = list()

for i in range(3):
  for i in range(3):
    listx.append('x')

for i in range(3):
    for i in range(3):
      r = random.randint(1, 9)
      list0.append(r)

user = int(input("Enter num:  "))

while True:
  for i, item in enumerate(list0, 1):
    if item == user:
      listx[i] = user
      print3x3(listx)
```

i want to hide random numbers behind these x

and let user guess them

but it gives error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 26, in <module>
    listx[i] = user
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

what can i do ?1

thanks

Comment: Ru SO for russian-speaking gays. Try SO instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не копируйте конструкции слепо. Если в первом случае использования `enumerate` вам нужно, чтобы `enumerate` работал начиная с 1, а не с 0, чтобы правильно отрабатывал остаток от деления, то во втором случае вам этот параметр (начинать отсчёт с 1) наоборот мешает, потому что нумерация индексов в списках идёт с 0. Правильный код будет такой:

```
  for i, item in enumerate(list0):
    if item == user:
      listx[i] = user
```

Comment: thanks but i have 1 question too. it prints table again when user finds 2 random number at once. can you help me solve this problem too? thanks

Comment: @emil You need to set some flag before for loop, something like `found = False`. Then set this flag when user find some number `found = True`. And print table after loop if flag is true `if found: print3x3(listx)`

Comment: @emil Try to think, you need to ask questions on SO only if you totally stuck, not if you not tried everything yet.

Comment: @CrazyElf думаю, не стоит отвечать человеку на английском, а просить его перевести на русский либо отправлять на другой SO. Всё таки у нас ruSO

Comment: @dIm0n Вы, конечно, правы, если хотите, займитесь этим, мне проще попрактиковаться в английском, хотя я и понимаю, что это не согласуется с правилами